# Дополнительный экран загрузки в приложении UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

Проект UWP Windows 10.

Стоит казалось бы простая задача: отобразить страницу с логотипом и крутящимся индикатором загрузки

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var coreDispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;
        await coreDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SettingsManager.login) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(SettingsManager.password))
            {
                invertUI();
            }
            else
            {
                Signals.invokeAuthOK();
            }
        });
    }
```

Колечко крутится, логотип не появляется.

```
<Image Name="Logo" Source="/Assets/SplashScreen.png" Width="310" Height="150" Margin="0,0,0,20"/>
        <StackPanel Name="LoadBox" Width="310" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <ProgressRing Foreground="White" IsActive="True"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

Подскажите как выполнить код после того как все элементы на форме отрисуются?

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Причём тут «отобразить логотип» к «как выполнить код после того как все элементы на форме отрисуются»? И причём тут содержимое вашего `Page_Loaded` к обоим этим вопросам?

Comment: @VladD Мне нужно выполнить некий код после отображения страницы. В разметке страницы есть изображение и прогресринг, так вот страница не успевает отрисовать изображение до начала выполнения кода, после его выполнения происходит переход на другую страницу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понимаю, приложение переходит на другую страницу прежде, что успевает отрисоваться изображение. Попробуйте вместо PageLoaded у страницы подписаться на событие [ImageOpened](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.imageopened) у контрола Image.

Также причина проблемы может более прозаичной и заключаться в неоправданно большом разрешении изображения. Дополнительно, если наличие альфа-канала не является принципиальным, попробуйте использовать изображение в формате jpeg.

И напоследок, у вас есть возможность самостоятельно задавать разрешение, в которое будет декодироваться изображение (по умолчанию, например, FullHD-картинка будет декодироваться в свое "родное" разрешение, 1920x1080, даже если конечный результат занимает гораздо меньше пикселей на экране). Вместо контрола Image у вас будет, например, Rectangle:

```
<Rectangle Name="Logo" Width="310" Height="150" Margin="0,0,0,20">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush>
            <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                <BitmapImage UriSource="Assets/SplashScreen.png" DecodePixelWidth="310" DecodePixelHeight="150" DecodePixelType="Logical"/>
            </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
        </ImageBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Обратите внимание, что у BitmapImage свойство DecodePixelType выставлено в Logical: система будет сама определять, какое должно быть разрешение в физических пикселях в зависимости от ppi и размера экрана устройства, на котором работает приложение.

И у ImageBrush, и у BitmapImage можно подписаться на событие ImageOpened, поэтому описанные выше методы могут легко комбинироваться.